# Fecha actualizada en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, contador

Quiero hacer un contador en Tkinter poco a poco. De momento quiero que me muestre la fecha en segundos (si, sé que es un poco raro...)  através de esta función:

```
def Date_secondsnow():
    now = datetime.now()
    Datesecondsnow = now.second + now.minute*60 + now.hour*60*60 + now.day*24*60*60 + now.month*30*24*60*60 + now.year*365*24*60*60
    return Datesecondsnow
```

La función anterior muestra la fecha presente aproximadamente en segundos.
**La cuestión es tratar de que me aparezca en un label, esa fecha actualizada segundo a segundo.**

**Condiciones:**

- Hacerlo sin definir ninguna clase (a ser posible)

Traté de hacerlo poniendo este fragmento de código al final de mi programa:

```
while True:
    Display()
```

pero no me funciona, no se me actualiza la fecha segundo a segundo (Display() está descrita más adelante).Los botones "iniciar" y "parar" hacen lo mismo pero eso de momento no me importa.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

#DECLARACIÓN DE FUNCIONES

def Date_secondsnow():
    now = datetime.now()
    Datesecondsnow = now.second + now.minute*60 + now.hour*60*60 + now.day*24*60*60 + now.month*30*24*60*60 + now.year*365*24*60*60
    return Datesecondsnow


def starcounter():
    labelQuestion = tk.Label(frame, text=str(Date_secondsnow()), padx=10 )
    labelQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

def Display():
    labelQuestion = tk.Label(frame, text=str(Date_secondsnow()), padx=10 )
    labelQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)





#Creando una ventanta principal
window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300+100+100")
window.title("Cronómetro")

#Creamos un frame como contenedor
frame = tk.Frame(window)





#Creando un label para mostrar la cuenta
#labelQuestion = tk.Label(frame, text="Cuenta", padx=10 )
#labelQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
labelQuestion = tk.Label(frame, text=str(Date_secondsnow()), padx=10 )
labelQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)


#Definimos un tamaño mínimo de la fila central delgrid para que quede un espacio entre cada entry y posicionamos el frame
frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=10)
frame.place(x=0,y=140)

#Creando un botón para Iniciar
btnSave=tk.Button(window,text="Iniciar",command=starcounter,font=("Agency FB",14))
btnSave.place(x=130,y=210)

#Creando un botón para Parar
btnStop=tk.Button(window,text="Parar",command=starcounter,font=("Agency FB",14))
btnStop.place(x=190,y=210)

#Iniciamos el mailoop
window.mainloop()
#App = Display(master=root)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera premisa en toda GUI es **no usar nunca métodos bloqueantes en el mainloop**. Esto termina ocasionando el bloqueo del mainloop por lo que la GUI deja de responder al no poder responder a nuevos eventos y redibujarse adecuadamente. Si usas un ciclo `while` dentro de tu hilo principal tu GUI simplemente se bloqueara.

Debes ejecutar el código encargado de actualizar el `label` implementando algún método asíncrono. Hay varias formas, la mas simple es usar callbacks junto al método `after`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime


def Date_secondsnow():
    now = datetime.now()
    date_seconds_now = now.second + now.minute*60 + now.hour*60*60 + now.day*24*60*60 + now.month*30*24*60*60 + now.year*365*24*60*60
    return date_seconds_now

def set_date():
    if state.get():
        date_seconds.set(Date_secondsnow())
        labelQuestion.after(250, set_date)

def start_counter():
    state.set(True)
    set_date()

def stop_counter():
    state.set(False)

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300+100+100")
window.title("Cronómetro")

frame = tk.Frame(window)

date_seconds = tk.IntVar(value = 0)
state = tk.BooleanVar(value = False)

labelQuestion = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=date_seconds, padx=10 )
labelQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=10)
frame.place(x=0,y=140)

btnSave=tk.Button(window, text="Iniciar", command=start_counter, font=("Agency FB", 14))
btnSave.place(x=130,y=210)

btnStop=tk.Button(window, text="Parar", command=stop_counter, font=("Agency FB", 14))
btnStop.place(x=190,y=210)

window.mainloop()
```

Básicamente la idea es:

- Usamos una Tk-Variable (`IntVar`) para mostrar la fecha en el Label. La gracia de esto es que se puede compartir entre métodos, funciones e hilos de forma segura y sin usar `global`. Por otro lado, se actualiza el contenido del Label cuando es modificada su variable asociada de forma automática.
- Usamos otra Tk-Variable (`BooleanVar`) para especificar el estado y poder parar el "reloj" cuando se quiera.
- Se usa `after` para actualizar el `Label` sin bloquear la GUI. Básicamente permite llamar a una función/método con un determinado delay sin bloquear el mainloop durante la espera. Hay que tener claro que **la función no se ejecuta de forma asíncrona**, solo la espera lo es (y es durante este periodo cuando el mainloop puede actualizar la interfaz). Si la función tarda mucho en retornar la interfaz se bloqueará, en estos casos hay que recurrir a otros métodos, como usar hilos.

En este caso se comprueba la fecha cada cuarto de de segundo (250 milisegundos). Dependiendo de la precisión y la carga al sistema que queramos se puede modificar esto.

> **Nota:** Usar la forma `from módulo import *` para importar es una mala
>   práctica que debe evitarse ([PEP 8 - Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)). Dificulta la legibilidad del código y
>   puede ser causa de errores al sobreescribir algún método
>   inconscientemente. **"Explícito mejor que implícito"**.

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, por cierto, la línea labelQuestion.after(250, set_date) ¿no podría dar un error de recursión como RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded?

Comment: @Mr.Baldan,  no si se usa correctamente `after`. El segundo parámetro de este método tiene que ser la **referencia a la función/método**,  nunca la salida de este. Es decir, si se hace `after(250, set_date())` se obtine ese error precisamente. Si hay que pasar argumentos al callback se pasan a continuación: `after(250, set_date, arg1, arg2, ...)`, nunca   `after(250, set_date(arg1, arg2, ...))`, ya que eso es equivalente a hacer `after(250, None)` lo que ocasiona que se exceda el límite de recursiones.

Comment: Aunque parece recursión,  no lo es.  `after` se limita a añadir el evento a la cola de eventos que tiene Tkinter, es precisamente el `mainloop` el encargado de procesar esa cola. Si tienes este error en relación al uso o modificación de mi código añade más detalles para poder ver que puede estar pasando. Un saludo.